# how to test show method in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How do I format the following line to do a request to `/users/1`?

`get :show, {format: :json, id: @user1.id }`

I have tried every permutation and bracket arrangement

Resulting error:

```
NoMethodError:
           undefined method `json' for #<UsersController
```

The entire spec file:

describe UsersController, :type => :controller do 
    require 'database_cleaner'

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

describe "GET users" do
    before(:all) do 
        @user1 = FactoryGirl.create :user, name: "Yakov", default_pull_rate: 10, default_push_rate: 9 
        @user2 = FactoryGirl.create :user, name: "Smirnov", default_pull_rate: 15, default_push_rate: 1
        @user1.save
        @user2.save

        @player1 = FactoryGirl.create :player, user_id: 1
        @player1.save
    end

    it "returns all users" do 
        get :index, :format => :json

        expect(response.status).to eq 200

        body = JSON.parse(response.body)
        user_names = body.map { |u| u["name"] } 

        expect(user_names).to match_array(["Yakov", "Smirnov"])

    end

    it "returns player for a user" do 

        get :show, {format: :json, id: @user1.id }

        expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end

    DatabaseCleaner.clean

end
```

end

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    include ActionController::MimeResponds

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json @user } 
    end
  end

  def create
    @user = PowerUp.new(params[:user])
        @user.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: can you pass :json in as a string instead? Do you even need to pass the format in? Does that controller handle both html and json endpoints?

Comment: It is necessary to declare the format despite the method only returning json.  Passing 'json' appears to give the same result.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the spec? maybe there's something in the structure of your spec that's making it parse incorrectly.

Comment: Are you sure the problem's not in your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is working perfectly. It is actually showing you a problem in your controller.

In your `show` action, you have

```
format.json { render json @user }
```

It should be

```
format.json { render json: @user }
```